# access click event and control of aspx page from class in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am using asp.net and have some page that uses the same code behind in `.cs`
I want to move this code like events to separate class 
how I can access page control and event click in `.aspx` from class? (I use the property for now)

this is link 
aspx: 
[Link](https://textuploader.com/dnzvd)

aspx.cs :
[Link](https://textuploader.com/dnzvo)

class.cs
[Link](https://textuploader.com/dnzvl)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well. You have to define your current page in load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page page = new Page(); //I think it is Page control. I am not sure right now, I dont have access to the code I made for that right now. But you propably get the main idea.
        page=this;
        Label c = new Label();
        c= Label1; //Might be c= this.Label1      
    }
```

and then from class you can do:

```
page.c.Text="I found you";
```